# apex development

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, force.com, code

I have a scenario, In which I have one custom field on opportunity and when I enter some value in the field it should search that account name in account object and if relevant account is found add that account to opportunity lookup field of account else create new one and link it.

```
trigger LinkAccofOppur on Opportunity (before insert)
{
    Set<String> name;
    Set<id> idname;
    // inserting new opportunity
    for (Opportunity opp :trigger.New)
    {
        System.debug('trigger new'+opp); 
        name.add(opp.Acc_Name__c);
    }
    //list of account where name equals the opp acc name.
    List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,Name from Account where Name IN : name];

    if(acc.size() > 0)
    {
        System.debug('greater than 1'+acc);
        for(Opportunity op : trigger.New)
        {

        }

    }
        else
            Account ac = new Account();


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're awfully close. This is a simple version that you can start with.

```
trigger mapAccounts on Opportunity(before insert) {
  Map<String, Account> accounts = new Map<String, Account>(),
    newAccounts = new Map<String, Account>();

  for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
    // Has an account name
    if(record.Acc_Name__c != null) {
      accounts.put(record.Acc_Name__c.toUpperCase(), null);
    }
  }
  // Nothing to do, abort
  if(accounts.isEmpty()) {
    return;
  }
  // Find existing accounts
  for(Account record: [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :accounts.keySet()]) {
    accounts.put(record.Name.toUpperCase(), record);
  }
  for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
    // Account has no match; create new
    if(record.Acc_Name__c != null && 
        accounts.get(record.Acc_Name__c.toUpperCase()) == null) {
      newAccounts.put(record.Acc_Name__c.toUpperCase(), 
        new Account(Name=record.Acc_Name__c));
    }
  }
  // No need to check empty list first
  insert newAccounts.values();
  // Fold the new accounts back into master list
  accounts.putAll(newAccounts);
  for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
    // Has an account to match
    if(record.Acc_Name__c != null) {
      record.AccountId = accounts.get(record.Acc_Name__c.toUpperCase()).Id;
    }
  }
}
```

No error handling is present in this code, so you might need to make some adjustments.

Comment: You used SOQL query in for loop which is not best practice better avoid it @sfdcfox

Comment: @SachinShah No, I've used a [SOQL for-loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm), which is perfectly okay. A SOQL query *in* a for loop is one where the query is within the body of the loop.

Comment: Is it needed to convert to Uppercase @sfdcfox

Comment: @SachinShah Strings as a map key are case-sensitive. One can choose to use either all lower-case or all upper-case, but either is desirable so that we don't create accounts that differ only by case.

Comment: Is there any other way using List @sfdcfox

Comment: @SachinShah You can use a List, but it's not the right tool for the job. You may as well ask why you would use a hammer on a screw. It works, but it's inefficient.

Comment: @SachinShah What you need is a working solution to the task. I would suggest you seek clarification from the person who gave you the task. Keep in mind that nested for loops across data have exponential CPU governor limit costs. So, for example, in a trigger of 200 opportunities, using a map results in 200 loop iterations, but using lists, will have an average performance of 20,000 loop iterations, meaning your trigger will execute 100 times slower, and may cause performance issues loading records in bulk.